# Printing out a particular row based on condition in another row

Tags: awk

apologies if this really basic stuff but i just started with awk
so i have an input file im piping into awk like below. format never changes (like below)

```
name: Jim
gender: male
age: 40

name: Joe
gender: female
age: 36

name: frank
gender: Male
age: 40
```

I'm trying to list all names where age is 40

I can find them like so 
awk '$2 == "40" {print $2 }'

but cant figure out how to print the name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us a bit more how your file/input looks like? How are 2 sets separated? Are "name", "gender", "age" the only possible entries?  Are the entries always in the same order? Please [edit] your question to include this information. At the moment we do not have enough information to help you creating a bulletproof solution.

Comment: I'm irritated by *list all names*. Your example contains only one name. Add a sufficiently large example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following(I am driving as of now so couldn't test it).

```
awk '/^age/{if($NF==40){print val};val="";next}  /^name/{val=$0}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** 1st condition checking `^name` if a line starts from it then store that line value in variable val. Then in other condition checking if a line starts from age; then checking uf that line's 2nd field is greater than 40 then print value if variable val and nullify it too.

Comment: Sure, please check now and let me know?

Comment: yeah that works...any chance you could explain how it works?

Comment: Added explanation now, please check it and let me know for any queries.

Comment: @blu10, could you please do let me know reason from removing this as an correct answer.

Comment: apologies...a mistake

Answer (score 2):

Using `gnu awk` and set Record Selector to nothing makes it works with blocks.

```
awk -v RS="" '/age: 40/ {print $2}' file
Jim
frank
```

Some shorter `awk` versions of suspectus and RavinderSingh13 post

```
awk '/^name/{n=$2} /^age/ && $NF==40 {print n}' file
awk '/^name/{n=$2} /^age: 40/ {print n}' file
Jim
frank
```

- If line starts with `name`, store the name in `n`
- IF line starts with `age` and age is `40` print `n`

Comment: I would suggest using `RS=""` and not `RS="\n\n"` This way you are POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 2):

Awk knows the concept *records* and *fields*.

Files are split in *records* where consecutive records are split by the record separator `RS`. Each record is split in fields, where consecutive fields are split by the field separator `FS`.

By default, the record separator `RS` is set to be the <newline> character (`\n`) and thus each record is a line. The record separator has the following definition:

> **`RS`:**
>   The first character of the string value of `RS` shall be the input record separator; a <newline> by default. If `RS` contains more than one character, the results are unspecified. **If `RS` is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a <newline> plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input**, and a <newline> shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of `FS` is.

So with the file format you give, we can define the records based on `RS=""`.

So based on this, we can immediately list all *records* who have the line `age: 40`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n"}/age: 40/
```

There are a couple of problems with the above line:

- What if we have a person that is 400 yr old, he will be listed because the line `/age: 400/` contains that the requested line.
- What if we have a record with a typo stating `age:40` or `age : 40`
- What if our record has a line stating `wage: 40 USD/min`

To solve most of these problems, it is easier to work with well-defined fields in the record and build the key-value-pairs per record:

```
key       value
---------------
name   => Jim
gender => male
age    => 40
```

and then, we can use this to select the requested information:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n"}
       # build the record
       { delete rec; 
         for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
            # find the first ":" and select key and value as substrings
            j=index($i,":"); key=substr($i,1,j-1); value=substr($i,j+1)
            # remove potential spaces from front and back
            gsub(/(^[[:blank:]]*|[[:blank:]]$)/,key)
            gsub(/(^[[:blank:]]*|[[:blank:]]$)/,value)
            # store key-value pair
            rec[key] = value
         }
       }
       # select requested information and print
       (rec["age"] == 40) { print rec["name"] }' file
```

This is not a one-liner, but it is robust. Furthermore, this method is fairly flexible and adaptable to make selections based on a more complex logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not averse to using `grep` and the format is always the same:

```
cat filename | grep -B2 "age: 40" | grep -oP "(?<=name: ).*"
Jim
frank
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F':' '/^name/{name=$2} \
    /^age/{if ($NF==40)print name}' input_file
```